# Issue Calling jquery function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my jquery code

```
(function($){
var W=$(window),
    D=$(document),
    Ht = D.height(),
    Wt = W.width();
$.fn.ThrowMask = function(){
             //Working code
        }
});
```

i tried to attach this code on button click  like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            ThrowMask();
        });

    });
</script>
```

But this causes error undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call the lambda function. use this instead

```
(function($){
var W=$(window),
    D=$(document),
    Ht = D.height(),
    Wt = W.width();
$.fn.ThrowMask = function(){
             //Working code
        }
})($);
```

Notice the two extra parens. Added jquery to function call.

Comment: You should pass in jQuery as param therefore $ is pointing to jQuery namespace

Comment: @Issac Fife Getting an error now...Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'scrollHeight': object is null or undefined

Comment: You probably need to put the whole lambda function inside the document.ready, or at least those four variables.

Comment: ...those four variables into the throwmask function.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Isaac Fife's fix, you need to call the function properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            $(this).ThrowMask();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Getting an error now...Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'scrollHeight': object is null or undefined

Comment: nothing in this code or the code you gave has any reference to scrollHeight, I expect that error to be unrelated to the given code.

Comment: Right, but it isn't related to this code. More than likely it is originating within the `ThrowMask` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code:

```
(function($){
var W=$(window),
    D=$(document),
    Ht = D.height(),
    Wt = W.width();
$.fn.ThrowMask = function(){
             //Working code which binding click event
             $(this).click(function (event) {
                  // do your click even handler here
             });

        }
}(jQuery));



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").ThrowMask();

    });
</script>
```